# What is the relationship between field_data_field_ and field_revision_ tables?

Tags: nodes

It seems that the field_data_field_ and field_revision_field_ tables contain exactly the same columns and data, except the revision table contains a row for every revision whilst the data table only contains a copy of the latest revision.

What is the point of having the 2 tables ?  Which table is accessed when a node is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

> **{field_data_[field_name]}**
>
> Standard data storage for a field. It's recommended you use
>   _field_sql_storage_tablename to get the name of this table.
>
> **{field_revision_[field_name]}**
>
> Standard revision storage for a field. It is recommended to use
>   _field_sql_storage_revision_tablename to get the name of this table.

For more [details](https://www.drupal.org/node/890070)

Comment: Yes, I've seen this documentation.  Doesn't answer my question though.

Is it just for performance on reads ( at the expense of an extra write when saving a revision ) ?

Comment: Not really @elb - where else would you store revision information for field data except in an identically structured duplicate table?

Comment: I think the point being made is that you _could_ have just a revision table, and read the current entry on load. I'd be interested to see if there was an affect on performance - probably minimal for typical sites.

Answer (score 0):

The revision table is to track changes and what they are. So the current content is still a change.

E.g if you wanted to revert back to an older version what would drupal do with the current version if it wasn't already in the revision table? It would have to then write it to the revision table so this now "old" remains tracked. What date would it give the newly added revision? It would also have to store somewhere else who was the author of that original change thats now no longer the latest

Cleaner and simplier to put any change directly into the revision table.

Also revisioning is optional so you couldn't say get rid of the data table and run everything from the revision table. You also wouldn't always want to read the revision table as there's alot of extra rows in there that are unnecessary